# %p vs %x in format String

Tags: c, string, format

Hi im a bit confused in String formats in C.
can someone explains me what is the output of every print of typed here?

```
printf("%p", pointer);
printf("%x", pointer);
printf("%x", &pointer);
```

Comment: How is `pointer` declared?

Comment: The first two can't *both* be right, and the third is probably wrong. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WeatherVane if the pointer is not void * the first is wrong, the second is wron and the third is wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane The third is certainly wrong.  As an address, it should be cast to `void *` and printed with `%p`.

Comment: @P__J__ let's wait and see what OP provides. That is why my comment was less than definite.

Comment: @AndrewHenle but you don't yet know whether the `%x` is wrong, or the `&`.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, but *something* is certainly incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

`%p` means “print a pointer.” You should pass it a pointer that has been converted to `void *`. `%x` means “print an `unsigned int` in hexadecimal.” You should pass it an `unsigned int`; it is not correct to pass it a pointer.

Suppose we have:

```
char *pointer = "Hello";
char array[]  = "World";
```

Then, in:

```
printf("%p", (void *) pointer);
printf("%p", (void *) array);
```

The value of `pointer` will be printed in some implementation-defined manner. (It should show you the address that is stored in `pointer`.)

In the second `printf`, the array `array` will be converted to a pointer to its first element, and the value of this pointer will be printed in the implementation-defined manner.

Note that I inserted casts to `(void *)`. This is the proper way to use `%p`.

In:

```
printf("%x", (unsigned) pointer);
printf("%x", (unsigned) array);
```

The value of `pointer` will be converted to an `unsigned int`. The result of this conversion is implementation-defined. It should not be surprising, but it may be different from what you see with `%p`. Additionally, an `unsigned int` may be too narrow to contain the full value of the pointer, in which case some information will be lost.

After this conversion, the first statement will print the value in hexadecimal (without a leading “0x”, whereas using `%p` often does include a leading “0x”). The second statement will again convert `array` to a pointer to its first element, then convert that to `unsigned int`, and then print that in hexadecimal.

If `unsigned int` is wide enough, it is possible, even not unlikely, that the values printed by this method will show the same hexadecimal values as shown by the `%p` method, but you cannot rely on that.

Note that printing these using `%x` without the cast to `unsigned` has behavior not defined by the C standard—it is an error to pass a pointer for a `%x` specification. You must convert it first. Your original code, without the cast, could result in the value being printed coming from some arbitrary data not related to the pointer, or it could have caused your program to abort, or it could have printed the correct address, or it could have done something else—the behavior is not defined.

In:

```
printf("%x", (unsigned) &pointer);
printf("%x", (unsigned) &array);
```

The address of `pointer`, rather than its value, will be converted to an `unsigned int` and then printed in hexadecimal. This will almost certainly be different than the result of printing `pointer`.

For `&array`, the address of the array will be converted to `unsigned`. Unlike the previous statements, `array` is not converted to a pointer to its first element. This is because `&` is a special operator that suppresses this conversion. It returns the address of the array.

The address of the array is the “same” as the address of its first element, because, in memory, the array starts where its first element starts. However, the pointers may have different representations, and it is possible that converting `&array` to `unsigned int` may produce a different value than converting `array` to `unsigned int`. Nonetheless, in most C implementations, they produce the same value, so you will see the same result for `printf("%x", (unsigned) &array);` as you did for `printf("%x", (unsigned) array);`.

Answer (score 0):

first is for pointers and the second one for integers even if the result very often will be the same. And this is explaining everything.  If you want to print pointer `%p` if integer `%x`.

All other deliberations are wrong as using wrong format specifier invokes the UB.

Comment: And very often will not be the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane if one does not know what is printed - he/she should start a bit easier carrier than programming.

Answer (score 0):

Let me illustrate with the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
   int  var;
   int  *p;
   
   var = 3000;
   
   p = &var;
      
   printf("value of var is: %d\n\n", var);
   printf("value of pointer with p format is: %p\n", p); //prints the address in the default address format
   printf("value of pointer with x format is: %x\n", p); //prints the value of p in hexadecimal format
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value of var is: 3000

value of pointer with p format is: 0x7ffe23863dd4
value of pointer with x format is: 23863dd4
```

Note the difference in the format of the address value; with the pointer format having a prefix - 0x7ffe

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd `printf` have undefined behavior: `%p` expects a `void *` so `p` should be cast as `(void *)p`, and `%x` expects an `unsigned int` so passing `p` is definitely incorrect.  You could cast `p` explicitly as `(unsigned int)` but you should probably use a larger type such as `%llx` and cast `p` as `(unsigned long long)(uintptr_t)p`.